# Laravel 4 Paginate and OrderBy issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to paginate with an orderBy tag and I am having issues with it.
Here is my code:

```
$posts = Post::where('draft', '=', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'id')->paginate(1)->get();
    return View::make('home')->with('posts', $posts);
```

But it returns with:

```
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()
```

Can someone help me with my errors. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the call to `get()`. The `paginate` method itself already does the database query:

```
$posts = Post::where('draft', '=', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'id')->paginate(1);

return View::make('home')->with('posts', $posts);
```